# batch script to append text from specific file to all files in subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, append, text-files, subdirectory

I need to append text from specific file to all files in subfolders of current folder (there is several levels of subfolders). The only tool - win7 cmd

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /r /d %%a in (*) do for %%b in ("%%~fa\*") do type "c:\somewhere\myFile.txt" >> "%%~fb"
```

Do a recursive search, starting at current folder and, for each folder found, for each of the files inside it, type the file to be added, adding it to the found file.